# URL for result of AJAX

Tags: ajax

I have AJAX for sort.

```
$.ajax({
            url         : orderby_params.ajaxurl,
            data        : data,
            type        : 'POST',
            beforeSend  : function(xhr){                
            },
            success     : function(data){
                if(data){                    
                    $('.list-thumbs').html(data);
                }
            }
        });
```

Everything works fine.
How can I get URL for AJAX result?
Such as: https://domen.com/shop/?orderby=price

Comment: What do you mean by "get URL for AJAX result"?

Comment: for example:
https://domen.com/shop/?orderby=price&order=ASC

Comment: And where is that URL coming from? Just provide it as a string to the `url` parameter? Like `url: 'https://domen.com...'`

Comment: Thus, I will need to create a line for each option. I would like this URL to be formed dynamically even when additional sorting options are added and so that in the future it can, for example, be copied and forwarded.

Comment: I really cannot understand what you're trying to achieve... if you want to construct the URL from other variables then look into template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: At the output, I want to get a link to the sort result. So that, for example, I can bookmark this result or send it to someone.

Comment: Then you need some kind of state management that modifies and reads from the URL. Visiting that URL will then trigger this AJAX request.